# Javascript - Canvas - overlaying a transparent png on a previousley filled color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I draw a rectangle on a canvas, fill it with a solid colour. Is it possible to fill it again with an transparent png, so that I can still see the original colour in the background?

Something like, dummy code -

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo( //draw a rectangle )
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000" 
  ctx.fill();
  var imageObj = new Image();
  function drawPattern() {
       var pattern = ctx.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
       ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
       ctx.fill();
  }
  imageObj.onload = drawPattern;
  imageObj.src = "images/dot.png"; //transparent png
```

I've tried a similar approach and it's not working.

Is there another way of doing this? Am I missing something?

Comment: It works for me on Chrome. Are you sure it is transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got will work just fine. Make sure you have a truly transparent PNG.

Here's a working example of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/BDXc7/

Comment: Thanks v much for the example, cleared things up for me. It was the png. *hangs head in shame*

Comment: Not repeating pattern with translated context shows transparency problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/e8dpzt2o/